# Devise invitable custom message not working - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-invitable

I'm using [devise_invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) to allow for user invites.

Here is what I have in my user model:

```
attr_accessor :custom_message
```

I created a new controller called invitations_controller.rb and here is what I have inside it:

```
class InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
    def create
         User.invite!({email: email}, current_user) do |user|
           user.message = params[:custom_message]
     end
end
```

And here is what is inside my new invite form:

```
<%= t "devise.invitations.new.header" %>

<%= simple_form_for resource, :as => resource_name, :url => invitation_path(resource_name), :html => {:method => :post} do |f| %>

<% resource.class.invite_key_fields.each do |field| -%>
  <%= f.input field  %>
<% end -%>

<%= f.input :custom_message  %>

<%= f.submit t("devise.invitations.new.submit_button") %>
<% end %>
```

And this is what I have in my invitation mailer:

```
<%= @resource.email %>

<%= @resource.custom_message %>

<%= link_to 'Accept this invitation', accept_invitation_url(@resource, :invitation_token => @token) %>
```

When I enter the email address, and the custom message and click send, this is what I see in the log:

```
Started POST "/users/invitation" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-15 15:30:18 -0400
Processing by Devise::InvitationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"x4Mb6AkF1GnZ5bHlipBbLh/X/T0zcHkkkxrtkHW7Y0U=",
"user"=>{"email"=>"email@gmail.com", "custom_message"=>"Test message"}, "commit"=>"Send an invitation"}
```

The email sends out successfully, I see no errors, but nothing shows up were the custom message is supposed to be, the custom message is blank from within the email that is received. What is causing this? How can I fix it?

Edit: I am getting an unpermitted parameter error on the custom_message

This is what I have in my application controller:

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

 protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:accept_invitation) do |u| u.permit(:username,:validate_username,  :password,:password_confirmation, :invitation_token)
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:accept_invitation).concat [:custom_message]
 end
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be this will work.

```
 User.invite!({email: email, message: params[:user][:custom_message] }, current_user)
```

If you are getting `Un permitted` error, you should do something like in either `application` or `User` controller.

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:invite).concat [:custom_message]
end
```

You also have to edit invitation mailer, since you are using `custom_message` attribute which has no value . You should use `message` since you are assigning data into it. So

```
<%= @resource.custom_message %>
```

changes to

```
<%= @resource.message %>
```

Comment: It did the exact same thing. Can you take a look at my form, is that the problem? Is the problem in the mailer view?

Comment: I'm actually getting this error:  Unpermitted parameters: custom_message

Comment: I edited my answer, can you take a look, I am getting the same error, am i doing something wrong in the application controller?

Comment: ohh i am sorry.. fixed the code. thanks @Thilo for pointing out.

Comment: are you doing this `devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:invite).concat [:custom_message]`

Comment: Yup! I have: 
  def configure_permitted_parameters
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:accept_invitation) do |u| u.permit(:username,:validate_username,  :password,:password_confirmation, :invitation_token)
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:accept_invitation).concat [:custom_message]
 end
 end

Comment: it should be `invite` instead of `accept_invitation`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50733/discussion-between-paritosh-piplewar-and-katie-h)

Comment: hey @ParitoshPiplewar just see your answer, I am facing a little same issue, can you answer my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31806998/how-to-send-custom-invitation-using-devise-invitable. It would be very thankful !

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at your log, it has the answer. Your parameter value is at

```
params[:user][:custom_message]
```

not

```
params[:custom_message]
```

Comment: Do I change this within the invitations controller?